# React Native: Why don't flex justifyContent and alignItems work for child <View/>?

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, react-native, flexbox

In React Native, I have a child view inside another view, but it doesn't center in the middle of the page. But if the child view is not inside the parent view and alone, it centers fine in the middle of page.

How can I make it so that the child view centers to the middle of the page while being inside another view (parentView)?

**Here is the code:**

```
  render() {

    return (
      <View id="parentView">
          <View
            id="childView" 
            style={
               flex: 1,
               justifyContent: 'center',
               alignItems: 'center',
            }
          >
            <Text>Center This to Middle of Page</Text>
          </View>
          <View
            id="childViewTwo" 
          >
            <Text>Don't center me</Text>
          </View>
      </View>
    );
  }
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just add `flex:1` to your parent View. I made a working example for you:
https://rnplay.org/apps/zHO1YA

```
return (
       <View id="parentView" style={{flex: 1}}>
          <View
            id="childView" 
            style={{
               flex: 1,
               justifyContent: 'center',
               alignItems: 'center',
            }}
          >
            <Text>Center This to Middle of Page</Text>
          </View>
          <View
            id="childViewTwo" 
          >
            <Text>Don't center me</Text>
          </View>
      </View>
    );
```

Comment: @antseburova Thank you! Works like a charm! Just a quick question, why is it needing to have nested flex:1?

Comment: It's like with regular CSS: when you want a block to have height: 100%, you need a parent block to have a specific height as well. Otherwise, it won't work.